# ES6 - Remove object from array based on conditions and return rest of the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There are three flags xstatus, ystatus and zstatus which determines whether the object with the properties name.is_xstatus,  name.is_ystatus and name.is_zstatus should be present in the array or not.

```
//All flags are true
var xstatus = true;
var ystatus = true;
var zstatus = true;

    var myArray = [
        {field: 'id', name:'is_xstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'id'}, 
        {field: 'cStatus', name:'is_ystatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'cStatus'}, 
        {field: 'money', name:'is_zstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'money'},
        {field: 'coverage', name:'is_coverage', operator: 'eq', value: 'coverage'},
        {field: 'nam', name:'is_nam', operator: 'eq', value: 'nam'}    
    ];
```

```js
var xstatus = true;
var ystatus = true;
var zstatus = true;
var myArray = [
    {field: 'id', name:'is_xstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'id'}, 
    {field: 'cStatus', name:'is_ystatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'cStatus'}, 
    {field: 'money', name:'is_zstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'money'},
    {field: 'coverage', name:'is_coverage', operator: 'eq', value: 'coverage'},
    {field: 'nam', name:'is_nam', operator: 'eq', value: 'nam'}
    
];

myArray = myArray.filter(( obj ) =>(!zstatus && obj.name !== 'is_zstatus')).filter((obj) => (!ystatus && obj.name !== 'is_ystatus'))

console.log(myArray);
```

I tried the above with the filter method. When the filter conditions don’t meet, it returns empty []. But what I need is if conditions aren’t met, return the Array with out removing any object

```js
var xstatus = true;
var ystatus = true;
var zstatus = false;
var myArray = [
    {field: 'id', name:'is_xstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'id'}, 
    {field: 'cStatus', name:'is_ystatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'cStatus'}, 
    {field: 'money', name:'is_zstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'money'},
    {field: 'coverage', name:'is_coverage', operator: 'eq', value: 'coverage'},
    {field: 'nam', name:'is_nam', operator: 'eq', value: 'nam'}
];


myArray.forEach((obj, index) => {
  if(!zstatus && obj.name == 'is_zstatus') {
    delete myArray[index];
  }
  return myArray;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach with the use of spread operator

```js
var xstatus = false;
var ystatus = true;
var zstatus = true;
var myArray = [
    {field: 'id', name:'is_xstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'id'}, 
    {field: 'cStatus', name:'is_ystatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'cStatus'}, 
    {field: 'money', name:'is_zstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'money'},
    {field: 'coverage', name:'is_coverage', operator: 'eq', value: 'coverage'},
    {field: 'nam', name:'is_nam', operator: 'eq', value: 'nam'}
    
];

let arr1 = myArray.filter(( obj ) =>(zstatus && obj.name == 'is_zstatus'));
let arr2 = myArray.filter(( obj ) =>(xstatus && obj.name == 'is_xstatus'));
let arr3 = myArray.filter(( obj ) =>(ystatus && obj.name == 'is_ystatus'));
let remainingElements = myArray.filter((obj) => (obj.name !== 'is_ystatus' && obj.name !== 'is_xstatus' && obj.name !== 'is_zstatus'));
myArray = [ ...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3, ...remainingElements];
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: my expected result doesn't match the output

Comment: which scenario is failing

Comment: expected result is {field: 'cStatus', name:'is_ystatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'cStatus'}, 
    {field: 'money', name:'is_zstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'money'},
    {field: 'coverage', name:'is_coverage', operator: 'eq', value: 'coverage'},
    {field: 'nam', name:'is_nam', operator: 'eq', value: 'nam'}

Comment: Modified answer pls check

Comment: since xstatus is false, onlt the coresponding object that contains the property whose name= 'is_xstatus' should be removed. Rest of the array of objects should be returned

Comment: thats wat is happening, four items are returned

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with chained calls to filter. The `zstatus` filter will remove all the elements with `is_xtatus` and `is_ystatus`, so they won't be available for those filters.

Instead, use a single call to `filter()` that tests all of the conditions using `||`.

```js
var xstatus = true;
var ystatus = true;
var zstatus = true;
var myArray = [
    {field: 'id', name:'is_xstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'id'}, 
    {field: 'cStatus', name:'is_ystatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'cStatus'}, 
    {field: 'money', name:'is_zstatus', operator: 'eq', value: 'money'},
    {field: 'coverage', name:'is_coverage', operator: 'eq', value: 'coverage'},
    {field: 'nam', name:'is_nam', operator: 'eq', value: 'nam'}
];

myArray = myArray.filter((obj) =>
  (zstatus && obj.name == 'is_zstatus') ||
  (ystatus && obj.name == 'is_ystatus') ||
  (xstatus && obj.name == 'is_xtatus') ||
  (obj.name !== 'is_ystatus' && obj.name !== 'is_xstatus' && obj.name !== 'is_zstatus'));

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: if the status is true then the object shouldn't be removed from the array

Comment: Since `zstatus == true`, `!zstatus == false`. So `(!zstatus && obj.name !== 'is_zstatus')` is false, and everything is removed.

Comment: but my expected result doesn't match the output

Comment: Barmar code will also work now, I have modified it

Answer (score 0):

why not add a judgement after filter?

```js
let temp = myArray.filter(( obj ) =>(!zstatus && obj.name !== 'is_zstatus')).filter((obj) => (!ystatus && obj.name !== 'is_ystatus'));
myArray = temp.length ? temp : myArray;
```